In a simple smartcontract withdrawAll function issue. Value in transaction is 0 ETH
I'm very new in development. I have a simple smart contract that has 2 functions. 1 is to receive payments from any address. 2 withdrawAll that works only for the owner of the contract.
The problem is that when the contract has some ETH on it's balance and owner calls withdrawAll function, the ETH value in the transaction is 0. The balance of the contract also goes to 0.
Contract was deployed via remix in Sepolia testnet. When deploying in remix via RemixVM Cancun everything works perfect.
Where can be the problem?

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyShop {

    address public owner;
    mapping (address => uint) public payments;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function payForItem() public payable {
        payments[msg.sender] = msg.value;
    }

    function withdrawAll() public {
        address payable _to = payable(owner);
        address _thisContract = address(this);
        _to.transfer(_thisContract.balance);
    }
}

Contract was deployed via remix in Sepolia testnet. When deploying in remix via RemixVM Cancun everything works perfect.
Also tried to to host locally a simple frontend page with withdraw button that calls Metamask to confirm the transaction. And Metamask showed ETH(balance of the contract to be transferred to the owner) with positive sign.

Share the address of the deployed contract please (on Sepolia), I will check the transaction

The code looks fine and it works fine in remix so I would imagine its the way you're calling the payForItem or withdraw on the deployed contract (hence wanting to see the transactions)

Hey! That is the contract address on Sepolia 0x3796341397BC7475f381F869404780BEE8AdcAa2

The deployed contract is slightly different than what is pasted above, instead of using call - use transfer like in your example above. Im sure this will work like it does in remix

payable(_to).transfer(_thisContract.balance); instead of _to.call{value: contractBalance}("");

Sorry, I gave a wrong contract address initially, I edited it. The correct one is this one 0x3796341397BC7475f381F869404780BEE8AdcAa2

The the value has been transacted correctly but Etherscan is displaying it as an IN  transaction when it should be OUT and shows 0 because of this. If you check the transaction details you can see it has sent the funds to the owner. How are you making the request to withdrawAll?
